# How to see count of outgoing and incoming commits in git cli

Tags: github, git

While working with eclipse and git, I was able to see the counts of incoming and outgoing commits in the project explorer. 
I am trying to see the same thing from git CLI but do not find any command for this over the internet and git documentation.

So can someone please help to get the answer how the git plugin in eclipse is doing this or there is any command which I may have missed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer, but if you just want a summary of the number of commits which have been made to the current branch, both locally and on the remote, then the base Git commands can do this:

```
git checkout your_branch
git fetch origin
git status
```

Just doing `git status` will say something like your branch and the remote have diverged by 3 and 5 commits, respectively.  This means that since you synched, you have made 3 local commits, while other people have made 5 commits on the remote branch.

Obviously, these are just stats for one branch, but it seems along the lines of what you want.